# Does Cantor's Diagonal argument prove that there uncountable p-adic integers?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Can I use the argument for why there are a countable number of integers but an uncountable number of real numbers between zero and one to prove that there are an uncountable number of p-adic integers?

My understanding of the proof is that there are an uncountable number of real numbers.

| Sequential Integers | Real Numbers* |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.346523... |
| 2 | 0.123456... |
| 3 | 0.005864... |
| 4 | 0.089457... |
| 5 | 0.124598... |
| 6 | 0.724598... |
| ... | ... |

*Where none of the decimal expansions terminate in infinitely many 9s

To find an uncounted real number you only need to change one digit in each row to a digit other than a zero or a nine.
i.e. `0.436511...`

Using the same argument could you not state

| Sequential Integers | 3-adic Integers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ...012012 |
| 2 | ...222222 |
| 3 | ...211211 |
| 4 | ...111212 |
| 5 | ...121212 |
| 6 | ...112122 |
| ... | ... |

To find an uncounted p-adic integer you only need to change one digit in each row.
i.e. `...202000`

Therefore there are an uncountable number of p-adic integers.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work, but sometimes the devil is in the details for these things. For example, note that your argument that the reals are uncountable isn't complete, because you need to account for the fact that the same real can have more than one representation as a decimal number.

Comment: Could you expand your comment? Should I have stated "a randomly selected real number between 0 and 1 without replacement"?

Comment: The diagonal argument is actually easier for $p$-adics, for precisely the reason Jephph brings up. Also, how are there countably many "non-p-adic integers"? Complex numbers are not $p$-adic integers, and there are uncountably many of those, to illustrate the ambiguity.

Comment: @elemelons I should have used integers. I'll make the change. Thank you

Comment: Dear Tolure, you just need to specify that none of the decimal expansions terminate in infinitely many 9's. Under this requirement, the decimal expansions become unique. Also, I would excise any use of the word "random." This is certainly not common terminology and could be confusing.

Comment: @Jephph Thank you, I'll remove the word random and add a note stating none of the decimal expansions terminate in infinitely many 9s

Comment: And to keep the real-number proof simple, you should also change to a digit that isn't $0$ or $9$ (unlike your example!)

Comment: I think the question has been answered in comments now. Could somebody write up a short answer?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments: Yes, Cantor's diagonal argument works exactly the same to show that the set of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ (and hence every set that contains it) is uncountable. If anything, the application in this case is easier than for real numbers, because the series expansions of $p$-adic numbers are unique, whereas in the case of real numbers one has to be a bit careful to deal with the expansions ending in a period of $9999...$.

In fact, the diagonal argument would also show that e.g. the set of power series $k[[X]] = \{ a_0 + a_1 X +a_2 X_2 + ... :  a_i \in k \}$ over any field $k$ is uncountable.

Or any set that you can identify with an infinite product $S \times S \times S ...$ of any set $S$ of size $|S| \ge 2$ with itself.